# How to add extension points in my library?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've started writing [DataFilters](https://github.com/candoumbe/DataFilters) a while ago after I discovered and used elastic search with it's wonderful lucene syntax.
The idea behind that project was first to learn new stuff but I was also wondering if I could create something similar to work with other datasources.

Long story short, I now have something that work pretty well (I think) with the BCL classes and I now want to extend it to support third party libraries like NodaTime.

The main parts are `IFilter` interface

```cs
using System;

namespace DataFilters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the basic shape of a filter
    /// </summary>
    public interface IFilter : IEquatable<IFilter>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the JSON representation of the filter
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        string ToJson();

        /// <summary>
        /// Computes a new <see cref="IFilter"/> instance which is the exact opposite of the current instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The exact opposite of the current instance.</returns>
        IFilter Negate();

#if NETSTANDARD2_1
        public virtual void ToString() => ToJson();
#endif
    }
}
```

with two implementations :
[Filter](https://github.com/candoumbe/DataFilters/blob/main/src/DataFilters/Filter.cs)

```cs
using DataFilters.Converters;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using static Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling;
using static Newtonsoft.Json.Required;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
#if !NETSTANDARD1_3
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
#endif

namespace DataFilters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An instance of this class holds a filter
    /// </summary>
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
    [JsonObject]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FilterConverter))]
#else
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(FilterConverter))]
#endif
    public class Filter : IFilter, IEquatable<Filter>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Filter that always returns <c>true</c>
        /// </summary>
        public static Filter True => new Filter(default, default);

        /// <summary>
        /// Pattern that field name should respect.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public const string ValidFieldNamePattern = @"[a-zA-Z_]+((\[""[a-zA-Z0-9_]+""]|(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+))*)";

        /// <summary>
        /// Regular expression used to validate
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static readonly Regex ValidFieldNameRegex = new Regex(ValidFieldNamePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the json property that holds the field name
        /// </summary>
        public const string FieldJsonPropertyName = "field";

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the json property that holds the operator
        /// </summary>
        public const string OperatorJsonPropertyName = "op";

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the json property that holds the value
        /// </summary>
        public const string ValueJsonPropertyName = "value";

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="FilterOperator"/>s that required <see cref="Value"/> to be null.
        /// </summary>
        public static IEnumerable<FilterOperator> UnaryOperators { get; } = new[]{
            FilterOperator.IsEmpty,
            FilterOperator.IsNotEmpty,
            FilterOperator.IsNotNull,
            FilterOperator.IsNull
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates the <see cref="JSchema"/> for the specified <see cref="FilterOperator"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="op"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static JSchema Schema(FilterOperator op)
        {
            JSchema schema;
            switch (op)
            {
                case FilterOperator.Contains:
                case FilterOperator.StartsWith:
                case FilterOperator.EndsWith:
                    schema = new JSchema
                    {
                        Type = JSchemaType.Object,
                        Properties =
                        {
                            [FieldJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String },
                            [OperatorJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String },
                            [ValueJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String }
                        },
                        Required = { FieldJsonPropertyName, OperatorJsonPropertyName }
                    };
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.IsEmpty:
                case FilterOperator.IsNotEmpty:
                case FilterOperator.IsNotNull:
                case FilterOperator.IsNull:
                    schema = new JSchema
                    {
                        Type = JSchemaType.Object,
                        Properties =
                        {
                            [FieldJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String },
                            [OperatorJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String }
                        },
                        Required = { FieldJsonPropertyName, OperatorJsonPropertyName }
                    };
                    break;
                default:
                    schema = new JSchema
                    {
                        Type = JSchemaType.Object,
                        Properties =
                        {
                            [FieldJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String,  },
                            [OperatorJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String },
                            [ValueJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema {
                                Not = new JSchema() { Type = JSchemaType.Null }
                            }
                        },
                        Required = { FieldJsonPropertyName, OperatorJsonPropertyName, ValueJsonPropertyName }
                    };
                    break;
            }
            schema.AllowAdditionalProperties = false;

            return schema;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the field  the filter will be applied to
        /// </summary>
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
        [JsonProperty(FieldJsonPropertyName, Required = Always)]
#else
        [JsonPropertyName(FieldJsonPropertyName)]
#endif
        public string Field { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Operator to apply to the filter
        /// </summary>
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
        [JsonProperty(OperatorJsonPropertyName, Required = Always)]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(CamelCaseEnumTypeConverter))]
#else
        [JsonPropertyName(OperatorJsonPropertyName)]
        //[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(FilterOperatorConverter))]
#endif
        public FilterOperator Operator { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Value of the filter
        /// </summary>
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
        [JsonProperty(ValueJsonPropertyName,
            Required = AllowNull,
            DefaultValueHandling = IgnoreAndPopulate,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
#else
        [JsonPropertyName(ValueJsonPropertyName)]
#endif
        public object Value { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a new <see cref="Filter"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="field">name of the field</param>
        /// <param name="operator"><see cref="Filter"/> to apply</param>
        /// <param name="value">value of the filter</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="field"/> does not conform with <see cref="ValidFieldNamePattern"/></exception>
        public Filter(string field, FilterOperator @operator, object value = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(field) && !ValidFieldNameRegex.IsMatch(field))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(field), field, $"field name is not valid ({ValidFieldNamePattern}).");
            }

            Field = field;
            switch (@operator)
            {
                case FilterOperator.EqualTo when value is null:
                    Operator = FilterOperator.IsNull;
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.NotEqualTo when value is null:
                    Operator = FilterOperator.IsNotNull;
                    break;
                default:
                    Operator = @operator;
                    Value = value;
                    break;
            }
        }

#if NETSTANDARD1_3
        public string ToJson()
        {
            return this.Jsonify(new JsonSerializerSettings());
        }
#else
        public string ToJson() => this.Jsonify();
#endif

        public override string ToString() => ToJson();

        public bool Equals(Filter other)
            => other != null
            && (ReferenceEquals(other, this)
            || (Equals(other.Field, Field) && Equals(other.Operator, Operator) && Equals(other.Value, Value)));

        public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Filter);

#if NETSTANDARD1_3 || NETSTANDARD2_0
        public override int GetHashCode() => (Field, Operator, Value).GetHashCode();
#else
        public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(Field, Operator, Value);
#endif

        public IFilter Negate()
        {
            FilterOperator @operator = Operator switch
            {
                FilterOperator.EqualTo => FilterOperator.NotEqualTo,
                FilterOperator.NotEqualTo => FilterOperator.EqualTo,
                FilterOperator.IsNull => FilterOperator.IsNotNull,
                FilterOperator.IsNotNull => FilterOperator.IsNull,
                FilterOperator.LessThan => FilterOperator.GreaterThan,
                FilterOperator.GreaterThan => FilterOperator.LessThan,
                FilterOperator.GreaterThanOrEqual => FilterOperator.LessThanOrEqualTo,
                FilterOperator.StartsWith => FilterOperator.NotStartsWith,
                FilterOperator.NotStartsWith => FilterOperator.StartsWith,
                FilterOperator.EndsWith => FilterOperator.NotEndsWith,
                FilterOperator.NotEndsWith => FilterOperator.EndsWith,
                FilterOperator.Contains => FilterOperator.NotContains,
                FilterOperator.IsEmpty => FilterOperator.IsNotEmpty,
                FilterOperator.IsNotEmpty => FilterOperator.IsEmpty,
                FilterOperator.LessThanOrEqualTo => FilterOperator.GreaterThanOrEqual,
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Operator), "Unknown operator"),
            };
            return new Filter(Field, @operator, Value);
        }

        public bool Equals(IFilter other) => Equals(other as Filter)
;

        public void Deconstruct(out string field, out FilterOperator @operator, out object value)
        {
            field = Field;
            @operator = Operator;
            value = Value;
        }
    }
}
```

[MultiFilter](https://github.com/candoumbe/DataFilters/blob/main/src/DataFilters/MultiFilter.cs)

```cs
using DataFilters.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using static Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling;
using static Newtonsoft.Json.Required;

#if !NETSTANDARD1_3
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
#endif

namespace DataFilters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An instance of this class holds combination of <see cref="IFilter"/>
    /// </summary>
    [JsonObject]
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MultiFilterConverter))]
#else
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(MultiFilterConverter))]
#endif
    public class MultiFilter : IFilter, IEquatable<MultiFilter>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the json property that holds filter's filters collection.
        /// </summary>
        public const string FiltersJsonPropertyName = "filters";

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the json property that holds the composite filter's logic
        /// </summary>
        public const string LogicJsonPropertyName = "logic";

        public static JSchema Schema => new JSchema
        {
            Type = JSchemaType.Object,
            Properties =
            {
                [FiltersJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.Array, MinimumItems = 2 },
                [LogicJsonPropertyName] = new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String, Default = "and"}
            },
            Required = { FiltersJsonPropertyName },
            AllowAdditionalProperties = false
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Collections of filters
        /// </summary>
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = FiltersJsonPropertyName, Required = Always)]
#else
        [JsonPropertyName(FiltersJsonPropertyName)]
#endif
        public IEnumerable<IFilter> Filters { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<IFilter>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Operator to apply between <see cref="Filters"/>
        /// </summary>
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = LogicJsonPropertyName, DefaultValueHandling = IgnoreAndPopulate)]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(CamelCaseEnumTypeConverter))]
#else
        [JsonPropertyName(LogicJsonPropertyName)]
#endif
        public FilterLogic Logic { get; set; }

        public virtual string ToJson() => this.Jsonify();


        public IFilter Negate()
        {
            MultiFilter filter = new MultiFilter
            {
                Logic = Logic switch
                {
                    FilterLogic.And => FilterLogic.Or,
                    FilterLogic.Or => FilterLogic.And,
                    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Unsupported {Logic}")
                },
                Filters = Filters.Select(f => f.Negate())
#if DEBUG
                .ToArray()
#endif
            };

            return filter;
        }
#if NETSTANDARD1_3 || NETSTANDARD2_0
        public override int GetHashCode() => (Logic, Filters).GetHashCode();
#else
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            HashCode hash = new HashCode();
            hash.Add(Logic);
            foreach (IFilter filter in Filters)
            {
                hash.Add(filter);
            }
            return hash.ToHashCode();
        }
#endif

        public bool Equals(IFilter other) => Equals(other as MultiFilter);

        public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as MultiFilter);

        public bool Equals(MultiFilter other)
            => Logic == other?.Logic
            && Filters.Count() == other?.Filters?.Count()
            && Filters.All(filter => other?.Filters?.Contains(filter) ?? false)
            && (other?.Filters.All(filter => Filters.Contains(filter)) ?? false);
    
}
}
```

[DataFilters.Expressions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataFilters.Expressions/) and [DataFilters.Queries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataFilters.Queries/) are two libraries that I also wrote and that allow to create C# Expressions or `WHERE` SQLs given an `IFilter` instance as a input (extension methods).

What i'm trying to do now is to provide an extension point so that I could write a new library (called `DataFilters.NodaTime` for example) that could handle NodaTime types somehow while deferring everything else to [DataFilters.Expressions](https://wwww.nuget.org/) (a library that I already released).

That extension point should add ability to handle nodatime type but I have no clue how to get started on this

For now, I'm thinking about something like this :

- create a new library `DataFilters.Expressions.NodaTime`
- create a new `IFilter` extension method in it : it will be tailored to handle NodaTime types.

The goal is to be able to handle NodaTime types both with [DataFilters.Expressions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataFilters.Expressions/) and [DataFilters.Queries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataFilters.Queries/) for example.

Could it be a good approach or is there a better way to handle this ?

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help me on this

Comment: Your question is opinionated and I'm not sure it is acceptable for SO. I only can tell that in my projects all my classes that can do filtering do it themselves, no matter is it explicit LINQ or cooked expressions. All they have method in interface like this `IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<T> query)` I can do any chaining of filters using this pattern.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply ... The idea  of that project was to abstract away the underlying language used to perform filtering so that it could be LINQ or anything else. So it could be an IQueryable or raw SQL underneath

Comment: It is another level of abstraction, but idea remains the same - chaining the processing in fluent way returning the same type as received but altered in some way.